# Cannot generate Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am simply trying to get the Simple Map (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple#maps_map_simple-javascript) for Google Maps Javascript API working for me.

I have this webpage (I have put in the API key and given the key access to Javascript API)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Simple Map</title>
    <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
    <style>
        #map {
  height: 100%;
}
    </style>
    <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

    <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
    <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<MY SPI KEY>&callback=initMap&v=weekly&channel=2"
      async
    ></script>
    <script>
        let map;

function initMap() {
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    center: { lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644 },
    zoom: 8,
  });
}
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I generates an html page but the iframe generate by the code effectively has an empty document inside.  It is

```
<iframe aria-hidden="true" tabindex="-1" style="z-index: -1; position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; top: 0px; left: 0px; border: medium none;" frameborder="0">
    #document
    <html>
        <head></head>
        <body></body>
    </html>
</iframe>
```

I must be missing something really simple and basic - please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why but yes, when i try to check your code i found that you didn't add css of body and html given by google map. When i add that it shows content inside it. CSS code i found is below-

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

Please check and respond